# Regex (PCRE) exclude certain words from match result

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to get only the string with names that is in Bold:

> author={**Trainor, Sarah F** and **Calef, Monika** and **Natcher, David** and **Chapin, F Stuart** and **McGuire, A David** and **Huntington, Orville** and **Duffy, Paul** and **Rupp, T Scott** and **DeWilde, La'Ona** and **Kwart, Mary** and others},

Is there a way to skip all 'and' 'others' words from match result?

Tried to do lots of things, but nothing works as i expect

```
(?<=\{).+?(?<=and\s).+(?=\})
```

Comment: If you're trying to do that from a programming language, maybe splitting that string on `and` would be a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using omission, you could be better off by implementing rules which expect a specific format in order to match the examples you've provided:

```
([A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*('[A-Za-z]+)*, [A-Z]? ?[A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*('[A-Za-z]+)*( [A-Z])?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/9LGqn3/3

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `\G` and a capturing group to get you the matches.

The values are in capturing group 1.

```
(?:author={|\G(?!^))([^\s,]+,(?:\h+[^\s,]+)+)\h+and\h+(?=[^{}]*\})
```

*About the pattern*

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `author={` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s,]+,` Match not a whitespace char or comma, then match a comma
  - `(?:\h+[^\s,]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching 1+ horizontal whitespace chars followed by matching any char except a whitespace char and a comma
- `)` Close group 1
- `\h+and\h+` Match and between 1+ horizontal whitespaces
- `(?=[^{}]*\})` Assert what is on the right is a closing }

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SIXZoS/1)